# impact of pl011 LCR_H WLEN bits

Tags: uart

the pl011 control register (LCR_H) has 2 WLEN bits which control how many bits are sent and received in a byte:
[image]
if I change the WLEN bits to 11 (8 bits) from 00 (5 bits), would it change the waveform that gets emitted at the TX line or the waveform would remain the same and just the 3 most significant bits would be zeroed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The waveform is different for 5 bits vs. 8 bits.  For a given baud rate, the amount of time to transmit a frame is less for 5 bits than it is for 8 bits.

These waveforms demonstrate the difference:
[image]